# How to find Firebase Crashlytics initialization file paths and double check that they work?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I am following the instructions for enabling [Firebase crashlytics on on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#initialize-crashlytics). There are a lot of file paths that I am not sure how to correctly resolve. The tutorial also says check Device Logs for checking if the script correctly uploaded dSYM files, but I can't see anything pertaining to this script in my device logs. Any advice?

Do I leave these paths as is for a default build or should I always be customizing them?

#### 1. Script Path

Who sets this **${PODS_ROOT}**? How can I print it to make sure it's correct?

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

#### 2. dSYM Path

Same question as above, but for **${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}**.

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
```

#### 3. Info.plist Path

```
$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

#### 4. How to check for correctness?

Am I correct in reading that this should show up in device logs?

> Your device logs display the Firebase verification that initialization is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Those default paths are correct, and do not need to be modified per release. They will always target the correct dSYM and root folder if you leave them as is. You can customize them to follow a specific upload path following [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#upload-dsyms), if you prefer.

In regards to initialization, yes in your device log, the Firebase SDK will indicate when it has been initialized. You can expect to see something like this "FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.2.2"